# ProcessorProvider not getting picked up by ServiceRegistry for Build-Time Solution

Tags: maven, wro4j

I've added `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.support.ProcessorProvider` to my maven project. The file contains one line which has the fully qualified class name of my custom `ProcessorProvider`.

Everything works well with the run-time solution; however, during build time my custom `ProcessorProvider` is not invoked.

Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/issues/detail?id=786&can=1&q=Milestone=Release-1.7.2) which is already fixed in latest development branch and will be released in version 1.7.2.

Comment: Should have checked the issues list! Thank you :)

Comment: is there a "contributing" guide for WRO4J? I've written a simple PreProcessor for [ngmin](https://github.com/btford/ngmin) that I think others might find useful.

Comment: Just fork the project on github and create a pull request when there is something useful.

Comment: Is there possibly a work-around for time time being, until 1.7.2 is released?

Comment: Either build latest snapshot locally or explicitly create a managerFactory implementation with processors configured programmatically.